# Making custom bitmap fonts for use in cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, custom-font, bitmap-fonts

I've been looking for a way to create my own custom bitmap font for use in cocos2d. All the tools i've found have you basing your font on an existing ttf, but I want to be able to create every letter from scratch in photoshop.

I want to be able to create a font with the detail of something like this: 
[image]

(i got it off a logo generator site)

Whats the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What do you want exactly? Do you want tool to create a custom font or just how to read your custom font with Cocos2D?

Comment: tip: check out how cocos2d uses the fps_images.png to display the fps numbers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to render detailed Bitmap fonts, check out [Glyphite.com](https://www.glyphite.com). It runs in your browser and can export high-quality Bitmap fonts like the one in your question. I was able to create a close approximation of your example on the site really quickly:

[image: A close approximation of the desired Bitmap font.]

(Disclosure: I work for Glyphite.com)

Comment: Great job guys, very impressive!

Comment: Link 404s, are you guys still around?

Comment: yeah, i'm really sorry, we had to close up shop. couldn't figure out a way to make any money to keep the server running :(

Answer (score 0):

Try out [Glyph Designer](http://www.71squared.com/en/glyphdesigner) - bitmap font editor for Mac